# How to target an image opened by an <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have an anchor tag that links to a png on the server.. when clicked the image opens.. I want to be able to target that open image so i can create a click jQuery handler to ajax back to the place where the image was opened. (Currently pressing back on the android phone refreshes the whole site)

Here is my current code..

```
<div class="fook">
<a href="images/food.png"><img class="down" src="images/down.svg" alt="" /></a>
<img class='food-menu' src="images/vfood.jpg" alt="picture of food menu" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible.  Instead you need a server that interprets that path, passes it to a server-side language to be parsed, serve up a page that includes the image along with some HTML that links that image back to the referrer or wherever you want it to go.  You'll basically have to override the default behaviour of serving up files directly to server them up as web pages instead.

Comment: Try adding the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute to the anchor tag. That will cause the browser to download the image rather than navigating to it.

Comment: Thanks Mike, That sounds like a good solution..

Comment: Thanks for the info Joseph

Comment: You will have to append the image to the website itself to be able to create a click event for it. Could be done with javescript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The browser displays the image natively, and isn't loaded inside your webpage so you can't target the image with JS if you are in the image resource

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible; when you click the link, you are essentially just opening an image, not a webpage. It's the same as opening a picture through your computer itself; you can't execute code.

The best you can do is use a plugin like jQuery's **[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)** to open the image in a **popup**, and then target that element. This would be possible, because the image would still be on the same page, where you have access to JavaScript.

In fact, Fancybox comes **pre-built** with the ability to 'click off' the image and return back to the page, and even includes a close button as well. I'd recommend considering using it to achieve what you are asking :)

Hope this helps!